# Disabling IPv6 to allow RDS Installation. What's the real solution?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2016, remoteapp

I've just experienced something for the second time on a fresh VM in Azure. This hasn't happened on Amazon yet, but has happened in Hyper-V on a fresh Server 2012 R2 VM.

Basically, I've setup a Windows Server 2016 VM with the intent of deploying Remote Desktop Services. I've selected Quick Start and received the following message:

> Unable to connect to the server by using Windows Powershell Remoting

Now, I've "fixed" this by disabling IPv6, but I have to believe that isn't the real solution. What could I have done to avoid this, if anything?

Comment: I would try tracking down the actual cause of the problem. You may find something useful in the event logs.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: @MultiverseIT I did. It seems like it wants you to manage and install RDS from a different server’s Server Manager. I discovered this when I found I couldn’t actually install and configure the RDS role with PowerShell on the same box.